# How to show and hide widget from android widget gallery

Tags: android, widget

My application has different widgets, after the app installation these widget are all shown in widget gallery automaticcally.

**My problem:**
How to hide ad show only desired widget?

eg, assume that some widgets are reserved to pro-user, if the user has a license in gallery can see widgetA1 and widgetA2, otherwise He can see only widgetB